# Unable to get correct output in MIPS

Tags: c++, assembly, mips

I have to convert the following which copies all the non- zero values to the array :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int source[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 0};
int dest[10];

int main ( ) {
    int k;
    for (k=0; source[k]!=0; k++) {
    dest[k] = source[k];
    }
    printf ("%d values copied\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

I have coded the following for it:

```
.data
source:   .word   3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8
dest:     .word   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
countmsg: .asciiz " values copied. "
          .text
main:

la $a0, source
la $a1, dest

loop:

lbu $v1, 0($a0)
addiu $v0, $v0, 1
sb $v1, 0($a1)
addiu   $a0, $a0, 1     # advance pointer to next source
addiu   $a1, $a1, 1     # advance pointer to next dest
bne     $v1, $zero, loop # loop if word copied not zero
loopend:

move $a0, $v0 
li $v0, 1 
syscall
la $a0,countmsg    # $a0 <- countmsg
li $v0, 4
syscall
li      $a0,0x0A  
li      $v0, 11         # specify Print Character service
syscall    
li $v0, 10 # Exit program
syscall
```

The output I get is "2 values copied", which should have been 6 values copied.

---

**Update:** Modified the code to use word addressing:

```
.data
source:   .word   3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 8
dest:     .word   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
countmsg: .asciiz " values copied. "
          .text
main:

la $a0, source
la $a1, dest
addiu $v0, $v0, 0
loop:
lw $v1, 0($a0)
addiu $v0, $v0, 1
sw $v1, 0($a1)
addiu   $a0, $a0, 4     # advance pointer to next source
addiu   $a1, $a1, 4     # advance pointer to next dest
bne     $v1, $zero, loop # loop if word copied not zero
loopend:

move $a0, $v0 
li $v0, 1 
syscall
la $a0,countmsg    # $a0 <- countmsg
li $v0, 4
syscall
li      $a0,0x0A  
li      $v0, 11         # specify Print Character service
syscall    
li $v0, 10 # Exit program
syscall
```

It gives me error: line 14: Runtime exception at 0x0040001c: address out of range 0x10400000

Comment: if value comes `{3, 1, 0, 1, 5, 9, 0}', your for loop will fail at the 3rd position..

Comment: Note that `addiu $v0, $v0, 0` doesn't correspond to `$v0 = 0`. It corresponds to `$v0 += 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which should have been 6 values copied

Nope.

First of all, you're loading bytes from an array of words:

```
lbu $v1, 0($a0)
```

The word `3` is equal to the bytes `3,0,0,0`.

Use `lw` instead. And increment the address by 4 instead of by 1.

Secondly, you never initialize `$v0` to zero before the loop.

Comment: I changed it to lw and changed the following addiu   $a0, $a0, 4  /
addiu   $a1, $a1 ,4 , it is giving me errors

Comment: _"It is giving me errors"_ is not a meaningful problem description. What _exactly_ is the error?

Comment: I have made changes in question above, the error is line 14: Runtime exception at 0x0040001c: address out of range 0x10400000

Comment: Well, your array should end with a `, 0` to mark the end of the array, just like in the C++ version.

Comment: How do I do that in MIPs?

Comment: You add an extra element with the value 0.

Comment: So i did add this line: add $v1, $v1,0 after sw $v1, 0($a1)
, It still gives me error:  line 14: Runtime exception at 0x0040001c: address out of range 0x10400000

Comment: Huh? You're supposed to add the extra element at the declaration of `source`. Why don't you just use the same contents for `source` that you have in the C++ code?